# Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert space. If $\mathcal H$ is not finite-dimensional, then $B := \{x \in \mathcal H : ||x|| \le 1\}$ is not compact.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert space. Consider $B := \{x \in \mathcal H : ||x|| \le 1\}$.

I've proven that $B$ is closed and bounded with respect to the metric $\rho(x,y) = || x -y ||$.

Now I want to show that if $\mathcal H$ is not finite-dimensional, then $B$ is not compact.

For this I've considered the ortonormal system $\{e_n : n \in \mathbb N\}$.

I must show that there exist a sequence $(x_n)$ in $B$ such that no subsequence $(x_{n_i})$ of $(x_n)$ is convergent in $B$ ? How can this be done ?

Finally, I've tried to find an example of a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, where $B$ is not compact.

Comment: Compute the norm between two distinct members of your orthonormal set (or just the square of the norm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $e = \{e_n \colon n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is an orthonormal system (hence $e\subset B$), then
$$\rho^2(e_m,e_n) = (e_m-e_n,e_m-e_n) = (e_m,e_m)-2(e_m,e_n)+(e_n,e_n) = 1-2\cdot 0 + 1=2$$
if $m, n$ are distinct natural numbers. Therefore, from $e$ it can't be selected convergent subsequance.

Moreover, from this, you can deduce that the unit sphere $S =\{x\in H \colon \|x\|=1 \}$ is also non-compact, since our system $e\subset S$.

Comment: How can I be sure $e \subset B$ ?

Comment: Orthonormal means $\|e_n\|=1$

Comment: Of course ... Should have thought of that. And I can use this system, because every Hilbert space has such a basis ?

Comment: Yeap! Every Hilbert spase has an orthonormal basis.

Comment: Can you help with finding a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ where $B$ is not compact ?

Comment: Take any infinite dimensional space, for example $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ as in the other answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18957/discussion-between-mher-and-user111854).

Answer (score 2):

The usual example is 
$$\mathcal{H} = l^2 = \left\lbrace (a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} ~ | ~ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2 < \infty \right\rbrace$$

Taking the sequence $(e^{(n)})$, where $e^{(n)}_n = 1$ and $e^{(n)}_i = 0$ for all $i \neq n$, we obtain a sequence that has no convergent subsequence.

To see that this holds, note that 
$$\rho(e^{(m)}, e^{(n)}) = 2 \cdot \delta_{m,n}.$$
Hence, any sequence that consisting of these vectors $e^{(n)}$ and converges has to become constant at some point.

Comment: I think you meant $l^2(\mathbb{N})$. $l^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a little more pathological and not needed here.

Comment: @Lolman That is true, thank you.

Comment: Why should $a_n$ be squared ?

Comment: @user111854 This is just an example of a Hilbert space.

Comment: Would the inner product be the normal dot-product ?

Comment: The inner product is $((a_n), (b_n))_{l^2} = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n b_n$.

Comment: How can you say this converge ?

Comment: @user111854 If you mean the inner product: Using the [Cauchy-Schwarz-Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) one has $\left\lvert \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nb_n \right\rvert \leq \left( \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2 \right)^{1/2} \left( \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n^2 \right)^{1/2}$. Both factors on the right side are finite by definition of $l^2$.